# Where is da SWAG?

Tags: discussion

Anything expected in this area? I liked the shirts presented in the Design Meta post.
Any kind of promotional things happening?
Or can we buy from anywhere

Comment: I don't know that this will happen given this answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store though I really liked the mug.

Comment: Ahhhh. Shame :(

Comment: @SteveRobillard They don't sell content anymore, but it is still customary for them to hand out gear to the top beta users upon graduation (last I knew).

Comment: @syb0rg that might explain the mystery package I have coming from NY.

Comment: @SteveRobillard They usually have a meta post about it though, and I can't find one other than this... so I can't say for sure.

Comment: @syb0rg like I said it is a mystery package and may not be SO related at all, I will post unboxing pics if it turns out to be from SO.

Comment: Define "top" :) ? 32 users with 3000+ rep, 57 with 2000+ rep .... Would we, lowly 2000-3000 pt contributors not be in the "top" ? At least we're in the 1% ....

Comment: @syborg the mystery package was swag but not from SO. It was a new tee from catchpoint from their devops quiz.

Comment: We have a back log of sites that we need to send user swag too. I hope to get to Raspbery Pi community soon! (realistically within 2 months)